# Append to arrays in loop

Tags: python, arrays, append

I would like to append losowanie1[0] when x = 0 to group1 and so on ( losowanie1[0] when x = 1 to group2...). The same with losowanie2[0], but it comes form other List.

```
import random
List1 = ['AAAA','BBBBB','CCCCC','DDDD','EEEE']
List2 = ['FFFF','GGGG','HHHH','IIIII','JJJJJ']

Gruop1 = []
Group2 = []

for x in range (len(List1)):
    losowanie1 = random.sample(List1,1)
    losowanie2 = random.sample(List2,1)
    # Here i would like to append losowanie1[0] when x = 0 to group1 and so on ( losowanie1[0] when x = 1 to group2...)
    List1.remove(losowanie1[0])
```

I tried:

```
('Group' + str(x+1)).append(losowanie1[0])
```

but obviously i cannot append into string.
I can do it without loop but wanted to make my code more professional. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the expected output? What happens with `losowanie2`?

Comment: Yes, but you can't make a variable name like that!

Comment: the expected output is: each element from list1 goes to different group started from group1 (not 0, then i add to x). Then first element choice by random from list2 goes to group1, second - group2 and so on. The number of lists and groups is not known at stage of coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `dictionary` with `keys` (as `'Group' + str(x+1)'`).
And then add a value to the `list`!

```
import random
List1 = ['AAAA','BBBBB','CCCCC','DDDD','EEEE']

base_name = "Group"
my_dic = dict()
for x in range(len(List1)):
    my_dic[base_name + str(x +1)] = []

for x in range (len(List1)):
    losowanie1 = random.sample(List1,1)
    my_dic[base_name + str(x +1)].append(losowanie1[0])
    List1.remove(losowanie1[0])
print(my_dic)
```

Result

```
{'Group3': ['DDDD'], 'Group4': ['BBBBB'], 'Group1': ['EEEE'], 'Group2': ['CCCCC'], 'Group5': ['AAAA']}
```

Comment: Why that "-1" please? What's bad?

Comment: Thank you, i wanted to use lists but if this can help i'll try. '-1' is not from me :)

Comment: Doesn't matter. Most important is to try to help! :)

Comment: I've updated with `dictionary` and `keys` corresponding to `groups`.

Comment: why use sample to get a single element? You can also start a range at 1

Comment: Yes, 'random.shuffle' would have be better here. Or `random.sample` of the entire population. I've followed the first script. It was the question (but, sure, I'll have to point to those questions!). And yes for the range, same reason.